# Programmatically create hierarchical list from two models

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There are 2 models:

```
class Device extends Object {
  int? id;
  Map<String, dynamic>? attributes;
  int? groupId;
  String? name;
  String? uniqueId;
  String? status;
}
class Group extends Object {
  int? id;
  Map<String, dynamic>? attributes;
  String? name;
  int? groupId;
}
```

How to merge 2 lists correctly?
[The results I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3mv6.jpg).

[In this example, a hierarchical list.](https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/07/14/expanded-multi-level-list-in-flutter-for-android-and-ios/)This suits me 100%.
I try:

```
late List<Device> devicesList;
late List<Group> groupsList = [];
late List<Device> _listDeviceGroup = [];
late Map<int, List<Device>> segmentGroup = new LinkedHashMap();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
devicesList = widget.model.devices!.values.toList();
groupsList = widget.model.groups!.values.toList();

groupsList.forEach((group) {
  _listDeviceGroup.clear();
  devicesList.forEach((device) {
    if (device.groupId! == group.id!) {
      _listDeviceGroup.add(device);
    };
  });
  segmentGroup.putIfAbsent(group.id!, () => _listDeviceGroup);
});
//As a result i get the map as i need.

List<Device> getListDevices (key, map) {
  return map[key];
}
return Scaffold(
// appBar: AppBar(
//   title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('deviceTitle'), style: TextStyle(color: CustomColor.secondaryColor)),
// ),
body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
...
  new Expanded(
    child:new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: getListDevices(1,segmentGroup).length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final device = getListDevices(1, segmentGroup)[index];
        return deviceCard(device, context);
      })
    )
...
```

But whichever key specified, the first element of the map is displayed.

How to get the hierarchical list of Groups and Devices correctly?

Answer (score -1):

It turned out to solve the problem like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  late List<GroupDevices> groupsDevicesList =[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var i = 0; i < groupsTemp.length; i++) {
      groupsDevicesList.add(groupsTemp[i]);
      for (var device in devicesTemp) {
        if (device.groupId == groupsTemp[i].groupId) {
          groupsDevicesList[i].children.add(device);
        }
      }
    }

    const title = 'Mixed List';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: groupsDevicesList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => EntryItem(
            groupsDevicesList[index],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class GroupDevices {
  final List<DeviceItem> children = [];
  /// Bild Group item.
  Widget buildGroup(GroupDevices context);

  /// Bild Device item.
  Widget buildDevice(GroupDevices context);
}

class GroupItem implements GroupDevices {
  final int groupId;
  final String name;
  @override
  final List<DeviceItem> children;
  GroupItem(this.groupId, this.name, this.children);

  @override
  Widget buildGroup(GroupDevices context)  => Text(name);

  @override
  Widget buildDevice(GroupDevices context)  => Text(name);
}

class DeviceItem implements GroupDevices {
  final int deviceId;
  final String deviceName;
  final int groupId;
  @override
  final List<DeviceItem> children;

  DeviceItem(this.deviceId, this.deviceName, this.groupId, this.children);

  @override
  Widget buildGroup(GroupDevices context) => Text(groupId.toString());

  @override
  Widget buildDevice(GroupDevices context)  => Text(deviceName);
}

// Create the Widget for the row
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);
  final GroupDevices entry;

  // This function recursively creates the multi-level list rows.
  Widget _buildTiles(GroupDevices root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty ) {
      return ListTile(
        title: root.buildDevice(entry),
      );
    }
    return ExpansionTile(
      key: PageStorageKey<GroupDevices>(root),
      title: root.buildGroup(entry),
      children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please don't include follow-up questions in your answer, or it may be mistaken as something other than an answer (in which case it will be deleted). One way of handling this situation is to remove the questions from your answer as instead post them as comments under your answer.